# Choose naive bayes model for continous feature, multiple labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

Imagining I have a data set, whose feature values are continuous, and there are more than two possible labels (eg: rain, sunny, windy etc), which naive bayes model should I implement in sklearn?

I am thinking about Gaussian or Multinomial. However, multinomial works for discrete features, and I tried gaussian, but it turns out that the accuracy of the prediction is like random selecting.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a sample of the data? It's unclear from the question what the input/output features look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive Bayes Classification (NBC) works with discrete values.
That means you have to discretize all features which are continuous. For more details, [this could help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218492/how-does-naive-bayes-work-with-continuous-variables)

Anyways, multinominal is correct because you have more than one label. But you should also keep in mind that you have to one-hot encode your labels ([OneHotEncoder in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)).